# Declaring fixed length variable arrays in Structure

Tags: vb.net, arrays

How do I declare a fixed length variable array? I'm stuck, any help will be appreciated:

```
Structure MyInformation
<VBFixedString(4)> Public ReturnStatus As String
Public VariableB(3) As String * 6  **Not sure how to declare**
End Structure
```

Thanks

Comment: yeah, this is a really good question. why can't we do `Public MyArray(3) As String = {"zero","one","two","three"}` ? I'm looking for a global array as a lookup table.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you declare an array of fixed size:

```
Dim n = 5
Dim test1(n) as String
```

This is how you reinitialize an array of fixed size:

```
Dim Test(10) as Integer
ReDim Test(25) as Integer
```

Also you can use a function such as this:

```
function initArray(n as integer) as String()
Dim test(n) as String
return test
end function
```

Finally you can build an object which is of class which implements the IEnumerable and use its ToArray method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i need fixed size string with fixed size array in Structur